# DataGridView to Word column headers are not showing

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using this code

```
Dim ht2 As Table
For i As Integer = 0 To _RowCount2 - 2
  For _col As Integer = 0 To _ColCount2 - 1
    Dim colType As Type = Form2.DataGridView2.Columns(_col).GetType
    If colType.Name = "DataGridViewImageColumn" Then
      Dim _image As Image = DirectCast(Form2.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(_col).FormattedValue, Image)
      Clipboard.SetImage(_image)
      ht2.Cell(i + 1, _col + 1).Range.Paste()
    Else
      ht2.Cell(i + 1, _col + 1).Range.Text = Form2.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(_col).Value.ToString()
    End If
  Next
Next
```

It is suppose export Datagridview to word but it is not showing column headers. mostly I am getting exception error in this line

```
Dim _image As Image = DirectCast(Form2.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(_col).FormattedValue, Image)
```

Comment: When you get an error message and decide to go online and ask for help, it is a very important message and should be included in your question. So what exception are you getting on that line?

Comment: My guess is a null reference exception. try checking the condition before casting as image and setting the clipboard `If Form2.DataGridView2.Rows(i).Cells(_col).FormattedValue IsNot Nothing Then`

Comment: Thank you for help. It was try catch exception error. Yes, thank you Tripodi it helped solve the problem.